# Pegar valor de um array

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando pegar o valor de um campo de uma tabela criada com Ajax. Com a função abaixo, todos os campos com o nome `qtde` aparecem, inclusive o que eu preciso. Preciso fazer uma conta simples de um campo digitado menos esse criado (`qtde - qtde_trans`), mas está complicado.

**Função que pega todos campos com o nome qtde:**

```
$("input[name^='qtde']").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

**Retorno (o valor que quero, na linha do calculo, é o 2000):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Função inteira que estou testando (com o this.val eu pego o campo digitavel `qtde_trans`):**

```
function calc_dif() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
       var total = $(this).val();
       $("input[name^='qtde']").each(function() {
         console.log($(this).val());
       });
       if ($("#qtde").val() < $("#qtde_trans").val()) {
          alert("Menor");
       }else{
       alert(total2);
       }
  }
}

$(function() {
  var $table = $('#locais');
  $table.on('change', '.input', calc_dif);
  $("#qtde_trans").on('change', calc_dif);
});
```

**Como a tabela é criada:**

```
 for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
                              HTML += "<tr><td><input type = 'text' size = '3' name = 'status[]' id = 'status[]' value=" + data[i].status + " readonly></td>";
                              HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '5' name = 'lote[]' id = 'lote[]' value=" + data[i].lote + " readonly></td>";
                              HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '10' name = 'endereco[]' id = 'endereco[]' value=" + data[i].endereco + " readonly></td>";
                              HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '6' name = 'validade[]' id = 'validade[]' value=" + data[i].validade + " readonly></td>";
                              HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '2' name = 'qtde[]' id = 'qtde[]' value=" + data[i].qtde + " readonly></td>";
                              HTML += "<td><input type = 'number' style = 'width: 25px;' name = 'qtde_trans[]' id = 'qtde_trans[]' class='input'></td></tr>";
                            }
```

**Exemplo da tabela que carrega conforme os dados do banco:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que deves usar especificamente `$("input[name='qtde[]']")`. Isso deve ser calculado num clique?

Comment: Isso, com o $("input[name='qtde[]']") que vc passou eu peguei o que precisava, mas quando vou para outras linhas ele exibe sempre o primeiro valor. Já é alguma coisa....Obrigado!

Comment: Pois, daí eu ter perguntado se é com clique. Mas vi agora que tens um `change`. É suposto ele recalcular todos os inputs ou só o da linha que foi mudada?

Comment: Só da linha que mudou. Esse change uso em outra função, que peguei como exemplo para começar....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o `.find()` e o `.closest()` para procurar somente na linha em que o `change` acontece. Seria assim:

```js
function calc_dif() {
  var qtde = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="qtde[]"]');
  alert(qtde.val());
}

$(function() {
  $('#locais').on('change', '.input', calc_dif);
  $("#qtde_trans").on('change', calc_dif);
});
```

Comment: Novamente me salvando Sérgio. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ótimo que funcionou!

Comment: esta dando erro no snippet no firefox

Comment: @Elizeu podes criar um jsFiddle que eu possa testar?

Comment: @Elizeu o código precisa do jQuery carregado e dos elementos do DOM. Como está na resposta é só o JavaScript relevante à resposta...

Comment: @Sergio entendi. Neste caso seria melhor retirar o snippet e apenas usar formatação de code, pois quando entramos no post e vemos um botão executar, o dedo coça pra apertar e ver funcionando. Assim que editar te dou um +1 em sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo trabalhar assim, Não seria o recomendado pegar o valor com o each() justamente por retornar de toda a lista, Neste caso eu coloco um **id** em cada **td** como o fiz, E pego o valor da respectiva linha(**tr**) clicada como no snipt abaixo, E mapeio o envento change do qtdtrans pelo **name** por id não funcionaria, Tentei montar mais proximo do teu código, Veja se consegue adaptar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name='qtde_trans']").change(function(){
var qtdTrans = $(this).val();
var qtd = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find("td[id=tdQtd] input").val();
alert(qtd);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Qtd</th>
<th>Qtd Trans</th>
</tr>
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td id='tdQtd'>
      <input type = 'text' size = '2' name = 'qtde' value='2000'>
   </td>
<td>
   <input type = 'number' style = 'width: 25px;' name='qtde_trans' class='input'>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id='tdQtd'>
      <input type = 'text' size = '2' name = 'qtde' value='5000'>
   </td>
<td>
   <input type = 'number' style = 'width: 25px;' name='qtde_trans' class='input'>
   </td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta é a forma como eu faria (snippet testado no Firefox 67.0.4).
Criaria o html da tabela já com o onChange no campo que vai ser alterado com a function de calculo passando como parametro o próprio elemento (this).

Assim fica mais fácil achar a linha sendo alterado pegando o primeiro parent (td) e o segundo parent (tr) e dar um find no campo a ser alterado.

```js
var data = [{status:"Status 01", lote:"345356", endereco:"endereco", validade:"05/05/2019",qtde:300},
{status:"Status 01", lote:"345356", endereco:"endereco", validade:"05/05/2019",qtde:300},
{status:"Status 01", lote:"345356", endereco:"endereco", validade:"05/05/2019",qtde:200},
{status:"Status 01", lote:"345356", endereco:"endereco", validade:"05/05/2019",qtde:400},
{status:"Status 01", lote:"345356", endereco:"endereco", validade:"05/05/2019",qtde:600}];

var HTML = "<table class='myTable'> "
HTML += "<thead><tr><th>Status</th><th>Lote</th><th>Endereço</th><th>Validade</th><th>Qtde</th><th>Qtde. Transferir</th></tr></thead>";
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
  HTML += "<tr><td><input type = 'text' size = '3' name = 'status[]' id = 'status[]' value=" + data[i].status + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '5' name = 'lote[]' id = 'lote[]' value=" + data[i].lote + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '10' name = 'endereco[]' id = 'endereco[]' value=" + data[i].endereco + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '6' name = 'validade[]' id = 'validade[]' value=" + data[i].validade + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '2' name = 'qtde[]' id = 'qtde[]' value=" + data[i].qtde + " readonly></td>";
  HTML += "<td ><input type = 'number' name = 'qtde_trans[]' id = 'qtde_trans[]'  onchange='calc_dif(this)' style='width: 50px !important;' ></td></tr>";
}

HTML += "</table>";

$("#content")[0].innerHTML = HTML ;


function calc_dif(e) {
  var fieldChange = $(e.parentElement.parentElement).find("input[id*=qtde]");
  fieldChange[0].value -= e.value;
  //ou qualquer outro calculo que queira.
}
```

```css
table.myTable {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.myTable td, table.myTable th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;
}
table.myTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.myTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #D0E4F5;
}
table.myTable thead {
  background: #A40000;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bb4040 0%, #ad1919 66%, #A40000 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bb4040 0%, #ad1919 66%, #A40000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bb4040 0%, #ad1919 66%, #A40000 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
table.myTable thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
table.myTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.myTable tfoot {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #D0E4F5;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
  border-top: 2px solid #444444;
}
table.myTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}

input {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```